# Customizing meta title tag in Just the Docs Jekyll theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

My friends website is made with the [Just the Docs](https://just-the-docs.com/) Jekyll theme and is hosted on GitHub pages.

Is it possible to change the meta title of the home page without changing the current title which is displayed on the website?

Currently the generated meta title of my friends website is:

`<title>Home - Lea Bosshart Text</title>`

In the **_config.yml** file there is following: `title: Lea Bosshart Text`

On the website it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself

In the file `_includes/head.html` I replaced `{% seo %}` with `{% seo title=false %}` to disable the `<title>` output of the `jekyll-seo-tag` plugin like described [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/advanced-usage.md).

In the file `_includes/head_custom.html` I added following:

```
{% if page.title == "Home" %}
<title>Lea Bosshart: Text, Übersetzung, Lektorat & Korrektorat</title>
{% endif %}

{% if page.title != "Home" %}
<title>{{ page.title }} - {{ site.title }}</title>
{% endif %}
```

Its also possible to add a script like the following In the file `_includes/head_custom.html`:

```
<script>document.title = "This is the new page title.";</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can find the file `_includes/title.html`:

```
{% if site.logo %}
  <div class="site-logo" role="img" aria-label="{{ site.title }}"></div>
{% else %}
  {{ site.title }}
{% endif %}
```

And the value `site.title` is what you change in the meta title.
You can change it directly with the text you want, or create a value such as `metaTitle` in the `_config.yml` and replace the `site.title` with `metaTitle`, and give the `metaTitle` a value in `_config.yml`.

**Update：**
I made a mistake in the above solution.

The reverse of this problem is also easy.By web inspector, we can find the title in the webpage is in the sidebar tag. Check the file [_layout/default.html](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/blob/main/_layouts/default.html), we can find the sidebar is based on [_includes/components/sidebar](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/blob/main/_includes/components/sidebar.html), and check is file, we can find the title we want change is based on [_includes/title.html](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/blob/main/_includes/title.html) I mentioned above.It means **both** the title of website and title tag are based on `title.html`

To solve this, we should know that the value `site.title` may also be used elsewhere such as `footer` tag.

So if you want only the title tag is different with others, you can create a new `_includes/title_custom.html`, and replace the `title.html` with `title_custom.html` in the [sidebar.html](https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/blob/main/_includes/components/sidebar.html)

Comment: I dont want to change the title which is displayed on the website. I want to change the title tag of the html head. In older versions of JTD I was able to adjust it in the file `_includes/head.html`. But in the current version this is not so easy. Look here: https://github.com/just-the-docs/just-the-docs/blob/main/_includes/head.html

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. However, this problem is not in the `head.html` file. I’m going to update the above solution.